# How to modify CakePHP Cart Plugin settings to use AJAX button?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using the [CakePHP Cart Plugin](https://github.com/burzum/Cart) to add shop functionality to a website. I want to add items to the shopping cart using an AJAXified button. Submitting the form works fine. I am having trouble to correctly return just the shopped item as JSON data in method [captureBuy() on line 210](https://github.com/burzum/Cart/blob/develop/Controller/Component/CartManagerComponent.php#L210).

Which settings do I need to use and where/how do I set them? Any hint appreciated!

This is the request which is being sent:

```
Request URL:http://shop.site/carts_items/buy
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:134
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:CAKEPHP=cd4611d0bf0100247928990a8efa72d0; rememberMe[User]=2....BmKdEs;
DNT:1
Host:shop.site
Origin:http://shop.site
Referer:http://shop.site/offer/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1553.0 Safari/537.36 SUSE/30.0.1553.0
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Form Data

```
_method:POST
data[CartsItem][foreign_key]:72
data[CartsItem][model]:Product
data[CartsItem][quantity]:1
```

Response Headers

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 23 Sep 2013 20:32:28 GMT
Location:http://shop.site/offer/1
Server:nginx/1.0.15
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Answer (score 0):

Define "not correctly". Paste your request and response from your network tab (in Chrome).

You don't have to set the items, the CartManager is already setting them to the view and serializes them. At least it should.

Make sure you have the RequestHandler component loaded as well.

Comment: I added the requested data, please see above. The RequestHandler was missing in the controller so I added it but it does not change anything.

Comment: Yes, the response is not json but html, see your response header. Try to debug it yourself and create a pull request if you can fix it or I'll do it as soon as I have the time. I'm a little stressed right now , so no promise to do it this week.